# bower fails with Repository not found

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, package.json, bower, mqtt.js

In the project there is `package.json` and `bower.json` with this content:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "dependencies": {
    "paho-mqtt": "*"
  }
}
```

There is also `ember-cli-build.js` with:

```
app.import('bower_components/paho-mqtt/src/mqttws31.js');
```

When I run `yarn` I get the following error:

```
bower paho-mqtt#* ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/larrytin/paho.mqtt.javascript.git",
exit code of #128 remote: Repository not found. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/larrytin/paho.mqtt.javascript.git/'
```

There is no such repository or is private: https://github.com/larrytin?tab=repositories

However, [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paho-mqtt) points to https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript

Output of `bower search paho.mqtt`:

```
    paho-mqtt https://github.com/larrytin/paho.mqtt.javascript.git
    paho-mqtt-cli-js https://github.com/jgsantos/paho-mqtt.git
    bower-paho-mqtt https://github.com/larrytin/paho.mqtt.javascript.git
    paho.mqtt.js https://github.com/huangguozhen/paho.mqtt.js.git
    paho-mqtt-js https://github.com/StickmanVentures/paho-mqtt-js.git
    eclipse-paho-mqtt-js http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.javascript.git
    mqtt https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js.git
    angular-paho https://github.com/bipolalam/angular-paho.git
    tsante-mqtt https://github.com/telecomsante/tsante-mqtt.git
    mqtt-wildcard https://github.com/hobbyquaker/mqtt-wildcard.git
    mqtt-q https://github.com/quentinlampin/mqtt-q.git
    mqtt-elements https://github.com/mqttjs/mqtt-elements.git
    mqtt-client https://github.com/centamiv/mqtt-client.git
    MQTT-bootstrap https://github.com/PCaponetti/MQTT-bootstrap.git
    mqtt-angularjs https://github.com/truongducanhskt/mqtt-angularjs.git
    angular-mqtt https://github.com/shellus/angular-MQTT.git
    angularjs-mqtt https://github.com/thanhson1085/angularjs-mqtt.git
    mqtt-connection https://github.com/sandro-k/mqtt-connection.git
    mqtt-elements-2 https://github.com/mozeal/mqtt-elements.git
    io-angular-mqtt https://github.com/jledun/angular-mqtt.git
    web-mqtt-client https://github.com/orbitbot/web-mqtt-client.git
    mqtt-browser-ws https://github.com/chenhuang511/mqtt-browser-ws.git
    aws-mqtt-browser https://github.com/komushi/aws-mqtt-browser.git
    simple-js-mqtt-client https://github.com/tebemis/simple-js-mqtt-client.git
    anh-mqtt-service-ws https://github.com/truongducanhskt/anh-mqtt-service-ws.git
    ng-mqtt https://github.com/vasco-santos/ngmqtt.git
    mqtt-browser https://github.com/sadeqzadeh/mqttjs-browser.git
    aws-iot-mqtt-websocket-sdk-js https://github.com/tapasbose/aws-iot-mqtt-websocket-sdk-js.git
    paho-script-only https://github.com/EMNico/mqttws31.git
```

There is no `https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript.git` on this list above.

I removed `paho-mqtt` from `bower.json` and executed: `npm i paho-mqtt --save-dev`.

Then when I ran `yarn start` I got this error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/58/4d0cprgn18b8v9yptpgnrk1r0000gp/T/broccoli-44755Swg20IggAAbv/out-272-broccoli_debug_debug_2_vendor_js/bower_components/paho-mqtt/src/mqttws31.js'
```

Any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

cleaning bower cache may resolve this issue,
open cmd as administrator,

```
cd {project-loc}
rd /s /q bower_components
bower cache clean
bower install
```

Then try yarn start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).